At what point in the Shuttle's design process was the 3g acceleration limit uncovered for the second stage of flight?
I'm watching a new documentary on the Shuttle, and one of the astronauts talks about how during the second stage, they limit the acceleration of the vehicle to 3g, to prevent the wings from shearing off.
This limit surprised me, as I always considered any acceleration within the nominal limiting one of 5-10g for consciousness to be the "target" upper limit, and that other challenges could be engineered around. Additionally, as I understand it the atmosphere is quite thin by the time second stage begins, so the stresses on the vehicle are already below Max-Q.
How was this limit calculated? Was it uncovered early or late in the design process? What implications did it have for the structural design of the Shuttle?

A perfectly valid question for this engineering site, but this site may not have engineers with sufficient knowledge of designing space craft. If you don't get any satisfactory replies repost the question on SE Space Exploration.

… especially since there's actual Shuttle engineers and astronauts on that site.

Going to flag this for moving to the other site, thanks!
